# Make filename with colon (“:”) in Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, shell, filesystems

[image: picture_1]

I created the file its name is 'asdf:qwer'.

'asdf' file was created, and I input some words.

'asdf' capacity is 0, Hex has no contents.

[image: pitcture_2]

But I can get words.

1. Where they come from?
2. What is colon(:)'s functions in Windows shell?

Comment: Under Windows and the NTFS file system the colon is an illegal character, **because it is used to open alternate file streams**. However all other characters **can be moved on and off the NTFS file system if a program with Unicode support is used**. [Source](https://kb.acronis.com/content/39790)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colon is not an allowed character in a filename in Windows. Or, more precisely, it is used to address an Alternate Data Stream of a file. So, `asdf:qwer` addresses the stream named `qwer` of the file named `asdf`.

This is very similar to the backslash. `asdf\qwer` is also not a valid filename, instead it addresses the file `qwer` of the folder `asdf`.

Comment: actually some windows APIs allows you to use : in filenames, and some do not. For example, the [CreateFile api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) disallows : in filenames, while the [NtCreateFile api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntcreatefile) allows you to use : in filenames. (why? dunno, I guess [Microsoft developers were drunk](https://xkcd.com/323/) or something)